# PhpMyadmin not working on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I created an EC2 instance on AWS and hosted Wordpress powered by Bitnami.

I used t2 micro to select free tier and successfully published with custom keyfile.
Anyhow, I need to host existing code to this hosting and I have issues accessing phpmyadmin.
It says "For security reasons, this URL is only accessible using localhost(12.0.0.1) as the hostname.

I have tried several solutions but cannot find the exact conf file.

Thanks in advance, please help me.

Comment: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is one of the solutions I found.
ssh -N -L 8888:127.0.0.1:80 -i ***.pem** @.*.*.*

This maps the phpmyadmin on user's localhost so the user can access using http://localhost:8888/phpmyadmin.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your current setup, but while a year before I face the same issue while setting up my company website.

edit config.inc.php file in your phpmyadmin installed folder .
Default path is :

sudo vi /opt/bitnami/apps/phpmyadmin/htdocs/config.inc.php

search for

## $cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] ='http://127.0.0.1:80/phpmyadmin';

edit the 127.0.0.1 to your domain IP or domain name

hope it resolve your issue.
I forgot the reference link where I got these detail I will add it later.

Restart apache after all